# How to refresh web page in Flutter without losing data?

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I want my page to be refreshed during the execution of the program after taking a variable in the program itself
And of course, I want these above changes to be applicable in piehart library
Thanks to those who take the time.

Comment: A "refresh" in web typically kills your entire callstack.  You'll have to treat it like a deeplink and ensure that your entire state is in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straight way to do it. But i suggest if you want to save the data of a form over refresh you can create a Model class of the Form Data and save that model in the SharedPreferences. You can update the values of the model everytime a User enters something in the TextField using its onChanged method.